# Cannot See the JS File Being Loaded in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

We are using ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Bundles. I did include my .js file in the Bundle, yet I don't see it in Chrome to debug.

The following code shows the bundling we do:-

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Pages/Company/_Create").Include(
        "~/Scripts/Pages/company.create.js",
        "~/Scripts/Shared/company.subindustry.js"));
```

At the End of the Bundling I do:-

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Can any one help me. Because this is way too annoying.

Comment: Have you tried locating it in the src tab in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: @RobertDinaro - Yes I did and I can't see it. Ctrl + P and look for the file.

Comment: @RobertDinaro - I do see the file being requested and pulled in the network tab, but cannot see the file in the sources tab, no matter what.